# Is it possible to instruct WCF not to serialize fields, which values are the default for the field type?

Tags: .net, wcf, xml-serialization

Inspecting the soap-xml produced by WCF I notice that many fields appear with their default values. Is it possible to instruct WCF somehow to omit such fields in serialization?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. If you're using DataContractSerializer, apply

```
[DataMember(EmitDefaultValue=false)]
```

to these fields.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately I do not work with data contracts directly. The business object framework I am using (CSLA) is dealing with it. I am wondering if there is some kind of a master setting, which can be turned on and be applied to all the primitive fields.